# How to Mirror files in SVN?

Tags: svn, configuration, mirroring

We have set of web projects, which has a lot of shared html resources - .aspx, ascx files.
We already made split them in project folder structure and I know, which folders must be same for all 4 projects, and which are specific.

It should be a way in svn how to do this, right?

In worst case, maybe someone can recommend good tool to compare files. I tested 4 of them and it is quite a lot of pain - they try to syncronize also svn internal files, and oriented to sync only 2 folders.

Last, we are using paid SVN hosting, not own server, and it will be not an option to install something on server

Answer (score 5):

Maybe defining Externals is your way to go:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html

Answer (score 2):

What comes to mind is not to use copies of the files but symlinks and put those under version control.

Otherwise, use a makefile after checkin out stuff from svn to get files in place from one master copy.

Answer (score 1):

For comparing I use beyond compare from [Scooter Software](http://www.scootersoftware.com).

Adding the common files in one place in svn and using a build script to replicate them where necessary gets my vote, you don't want bug fixes to have to be done in several places, or worse, if some type of replication of the files is used, not knowing where to do the bug fix in the first place.